# Merge elements in list by property

Tags: c#

#### Context

I have a list of time intervals. Time interval type is `HistoMesures`.

Each `HistoMesure` is defined by a `Debut` (begin) property, a `Fin` (end) property, and a `Commentaires` (a little note) property.

My list is made in such a way that :

- All `HistoMesure` are *exclusive*, I mean that they can't be overlapping each other.
- The list is sorted by `Debut`, so by the beggining of the interval.
- **Edit** : All `HistoMesure` are contiguous in this configuration.

#### Question

I want to merge (transform two little intervals in one big interval) all **adjacent** `HistoMesure` which have the same `Commentaires`. Currently I achieve this that way :

```
//sortedHistos type is List<HistoMesure>
int i = 0;
while (i < sortedHistos.Count - 1)
{
    if (sortedHistos[i].Commentaires == sortedHistos[i + 1].Commentaires)
    {
        sortedHistos[i].Fin = sortedHistos[i + 1].Fin;
        sortedHistos.RemoveAt(i + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

But I feel that it exists a more elegant way to do this, maybe with LINQ. Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: What if you have time intervals A, B, C where A and C have same note. What to do with interval B which is included into merged interval AC?

Comment: Are you merging or removing duplicates?

Comment: @captainsac It is imposible, as I guarantee that there is no overlapping or duplicate. Each interval excludes the others.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I forgot to precise that I want to merge only the **adjacent** intervals. So if B is between A and C and doesn't have the same note, nothing changes.

Comment: You should keep in mind that using LINQ is a language for queries. Sure you can do other stuff with it, running a loop and so on but why you should do this? It's a tool to define WHAT you get not a tool to define HOW you get it! So using it you'll leave the concrete implementation of HOW to get what you asked for.

Comment: @user743414 You are right, it was only a feeling. In all case, I am not satisfied of my solution, so I am looking for a better suggestion.

Comment: We decided not to use it, because most times(!) it's slower than the "old" way of doing it. Decision has to be taken by everyone self. You just have to keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Linq and borrowing from [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/04/21/the-groupadjacent-extension-method.aspx) to group by adjacent values, this should work:

Your query:

```
var filteredHistos = sortedHistos
    .GroupAdjacent(h => h.Commentaires)
    .Select(g => new HistoMesure
    {
        Debut = g.First().Debut,
        Fin = g.Last().Fin,
        Commentaires = g.Key
    });
```

And copying from the article, the rest of the code to group by:

```
public class GroupOfAdjacent<TSource, TKey> : IEnumerable<TSource>, IGrouping<TKey, TSource>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    private List<TSource> GroupList { get; set; }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<TSource> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var s in GroupList)
            yield return s;
    }
    public GroupOfAdjacent(List<TSource> source, TKey key)
    {
        GroupList = source;
        Key = key;
    }
}
public static class LocalExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupAdjacent<TSource, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        TKey last = default(TKey);
        bool haveLast = false;
        List<TSource> list = new List<TSource>();
        foreach (TSource s in source)
        {
            TKey k = keySelector(s);
            if (haveLast)
            {
                if (!k.Equals(last))
                {
                    yield return new GroupOfAdjacent<TSource, TKey>(list, last);
                    list = new List<TSource>();
                    list.Add(s);
                    last = k;
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Add(s);
                    last = k;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(s);
                last = k;
                haveLast = true;
            }
        }
        if (haveLast)
            yield return new GroupOfAdjacent<TSource, TKey>(list, last);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is too long for me, as I need to do this a single time. I was looking for a simpler way. However this is interesting and I keep it in memory.

Comment: I simply just don't want to create new classes that I will never use except this time. I was looking for a immediate solution to put directly in my code from existing methods. But I will accept your suggestion as it answers to the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution works fine, I would keep it.

Don't try too hard to use LINQ if it doesn't match your requirements. LINQ is great to write **queries** (this is the Q of LINQ), not so great to modify existing lists.

Comment: I thought that it was not elegant at all. But if there is not really better way, I am ok with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This code will produce overlapping merged intervals. I.e. if you have intervals A, B, C where A and C have same commentaries, result will be AC, B:

```
var result = from h in sortedHistos
             group h by h.Commentaires into g
             select new HistoMesure {
                 Debut = g.First().Debut, // thus you have sorted entries
                 Fin = g.Last().Fin,
                 Commentaires = g.Key
             };
```

You can use `Min` and `Max` if intervals are not sorted.

---

UPDATE: There is no default LINQ operator which allows you to create adjacent groups. But you always can create one. Here is `IEnumerable<T>` extension (I skipped arguments check):

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GroupAdjacent<TKey, TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TElement> source, Func<TElement, TKey> keySelector)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if(!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {
            var comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
            var group = new Grouping<TKey, TElement>(keySelector(iterator.Current));
            group.Add(iterator.Current);

            while(iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                TKey key = keySelector(iterator.Current);
                if (comparer.Compare(key, group.Key) != 0)
                {
                    yield return group;
                    group = new Grouping<TKey, TElement>(key);
                }

                group.Add(iterator.Current);                        
            }

            if (group.Any())
                yield return group;
        }
    }
}
```

This extension creates groups of adjacent elements which have same key value. Unfortunately all implementations of IGrouping in .NET are internal, so you need yours:

```
public class Grouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    private List<TElement> elements = new List<TElement>();

    public Grouping(TKey key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public TKey Key { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return elements.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(TElement element)
    {
        elements.Add(element);
    }
}
```

And now your code will look like:

```
var result = sortedHistos.GroupAdjacent(h => h.Commentaries)
                         .Select(g => new HistoMesure {
                              Debut = g.Min(h => h.Debut),
                              Fin = g.Max(h => h.Fin),
                              Commentaries = g.Key
                          });
```

Comment: I am sorry If I have not been clear. If I have intervals A, B, C, D where B and C have same commentaries, I want the result to be A, BC, D. If A, B and C have same commentaries, I want the result to be ABC, D. But if A and C have same commentaries, I want the result to be A, B, C, D. I want to merge only **adjacent** elements which have same commentary.

Comment: @Chostakovitch ok, it was not clear from your question, that's why I wrote comment. I'll update answer

Comment: @Chostakovitch updated. Keep in mind that `GroupAdjacent` is an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) and it should be in static class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like this:

```
        var mergedMesures = mesures
            .GroupBy(_ => _.Commentaires)
            .Select(_ => new HistoMesures
            {
                Debut = _.Min(item => item.Debut),
                Fin = _.Max(item => item.Fin),
                Commentaires = _.Key
            });
```